# Splitting a delimeted string with 2 values .SQL Server 2008 . Can you help?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am passing a delimited string to a stored procedure that is composed by empId|ProductId + a comma as delimiter
with the purpose of filling a link table. using SQL Server 2008

```
     EmployeeOrderLink  Table to be filled
     EmpId
     OrderId
     ProductId
```

Example of a possible key

```
     MyKeyIds="EmpId|ProductId,
     EG 2232|33,4555|111,43343|65 etc...
```

How do I loop through the string split it and insert into the table eg

```
   while MyKeyIds  ???
   Logic --PLEASE NOTE THAT EACH KEY IS COMPOSED BY 2 VALUES 
 AND SEPARATED BY THE COMMA.DELIMETER IS USED TO SEPARATE THE INNER VALUES OF THE KEY

         @myEmpID=--Get EmpId from split string
         @myProductId =Get productId from split string

         INSERT EmployeeOrderLinkend(EmpId,OrderId,ProductId)
         VALUES(@myEmpID,@OrderIdPassedAsParamInSP, @myProductId)
    END
```

Any suggestion on how to split the above key and extract the appropriate values?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/20009) is an example of the split function in SQL. Another [tutorial is this](http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/09/sql-function-split.html). Using it I think I would do the below to split at the comma. You would have to then add the code to split at the `|` also.

```
DECLARE @MyKeyIds NVARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @IDset NVARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @Pos INT
DECLARE @NextPos INT
DECLARE @Delimiter NVARCHAR(40)

SET @Delimiter = ','
Set @MyKeyIds='2232|33,4555|111,43343|65'+ @Delimiter 
SET @Pos = charindex(@Delimiter, @MyKeyIds)

WHILE (@pos <> 0)
BEGIN
    SET @IDset = substring(@MyKeyIds,1,@Pos - 1)
    SELECT @IDset -- Show Results
    SET @MyKeyIds = substring(@MyKeyIds,@Pos+1,len(@MyKeyIds))
    SET @Pos = charindex(@Delimiter,@MyKeyIds)
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the link 
Could you show me how you would use it to extract my 2 separate values.As a said each key is composed of two values that I need to extract.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi Thanks for the example very grateful.As you said you can do the same with split function.I have done the following
                  CREATE TABLE #tmpKeys (setKeys varchar(200))
 
  insert into #tmpKeys(setKeys)
  select * from fnSplit(@MyKeyIds,',') 
  
  select * from #tmpKeys
  
  DROP TABLE #tmpKeys
The above will split at comma.Fine.but now I need to split at | .
How do I do that in one go and populate my rows?
Thanks for any input

Comment: You just have to do what I already have there just use the @IDset as in the place of @MyKeyIds and set the @Delimiter, or have a different variable, set to | instead of ,. Guessing you would have to put it within the while somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This code will parse the string by comma and then split the result based on the position of the pipe:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE 
  @keyPair VARCHAR(1000),
  @myEmpID VARCHAR(1000),
  @myProductID VARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE @myKeyIDs VARCHAR(1000)
SET @myKeyIDs = '2232|33,4555|111,43343|65'

DECLARE
  @len INT,
  @pos INT,
  @found INT

SELECT
  @len = LEN(@myKeyIDs),
  @pos = 1

SET @myKeyIDs = @myKeyIDs + ','

/* Find the first instance of a comma */
SET @found = CHARINDEX(',', @myKeyIDs, @pos)

WHILE @found > 0
BEGIN  

  /* The key pair starts at the @pos position and goes */
  /* to the @found position minus the @pos position   */
  SET @keyPair= SUBSTRING(@myKeyIDs, @pos, @found - (@pos))

  /* Double-check that pipe exists to avoid failure */
  /* If no pipe exists, assume value is myEmpID     */
  IF CHARINDEX('|',@keyPair) = 0
  BEGIN
    SET @myEmpID = NULLIF(@keyPair, '')
    SET @myProductID = NULL
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    /* myEmpID is everything left of the pipe */
    /* myProductID is everything on the right */
    SET @myEmpID = NULLIF(SUBSTRING(@keyPair, 1, 
        CHARINDEX('|', @keyPair) - 1), '')
    SET @myProductID = NULLIF(SUBSTRING(@keyPair, 
        CHARINDEX('|', @keyPair) + 1, LEN(@keyPair) - 1), '')
  END

  /*
  INSERT EmployeeOrderLinkend(EmpId,OrderId,ProductId) 
  VALUES(@myEmpID,@OrderIdPassedAsParamInSP, @myProductId) 
  */
  SELECT @myEmpID AS myEmpID, @myProductID AS myProductID

  /* Move to the next position and search again */
  SET @pos = @found + 1
  SET @found = CHARINDEX(',', @myKeyIDs, @pos)

END
```

One of the problems with string parsing is trying to handle all the edge cases. You have to prepare for things like missing commas, missing pipes, too many pipes, confirming your values are numeric, and so on. We have also migrated to using Table-Valued Parameters when possible...

Comment: wow,Thanks for your effort trying to digest it.
Using a split function as many suggested I managed to create a table with a row of keys eg 11|22 etc.
Now given that I have a temporary table of rows like that
Can I somehow use the split function again and create another table with 2 columns EG EmpId and ProductId from my temporary table?

Comment: insert into #tmpKeys(setKeys)
  select * from fnSplit(@MyKeyIds,',') 
now given that I have the table i  need somehow create another table with rows of EmpId and productid
sorry a bit rusty on sql any ideas

Comment: If you look at the code below /* myProductID is everything on the right*/, you could use that (or some variation) to determine what is on the left and right of the Pipe delimiter and apply that to the setKeys column...

Answer (score 0):

Another SQL [split](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx) function. Basically, a split() function will create a table from your delimited list. You can then join against that table as if it were a "real" table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would I use it and get my 2 values.Could you show me a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

As you're on SQL Server 2008 you can use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to avoid this issue entirely.

If you are calling the stored proc from ADO.NET [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) might be useful.